# function onClick in bootstrtap Card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, card

I need 3 cards so that when I click on one of them, the selection changes, I tried to implement it this way, but when I refresh the page, it registers all 3 clicks, but further ones do not reach, how can this be implemented?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Card,CardGroup } from 'react-bootstrap'
import A2 from '../assets/A2example.png'
import A3 from '../assets/A3example.png'
import A4 from '../assets/A4example.png'

function portretSize(a){
    console.log(a);
}


export default class ZakazPortreta extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className = "ZakazDiv">
                <h2>Choose your preferred option:</h2>
                <CardGroup>
                    <Card>
                        <Card.Body className = "cards" onClick = {portretSize(4)}>
                            <Card.Title>А4</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">210×297 мм</Card.Subtitle>
                            <Card.Text>
                                <img src = {A4} width = "370" height = "550"/>
                            </Card.Text>
                            <Card.Link href="#">Card Link</Card.Link>
                            <Card.Link href="#">Another Link</Card.Link>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    <Card >
                        <Card.Body className = "cards" onClick = {portretSize(3)}>
                            <Card.Title>А3</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">297 x 420 мм</Card.Subtitle>
                            <Card.Text>
                            <img src = {A3} width = "370" height = "550"/>
                            </Card.Text>
                            <Card.Link href="#">Card Link</Card.Link>
                            <Card.Link href="#">Another Link</Card.Link>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    <Card >
                        <Card.Body className = "cards" onClick = {portretSize(2)}>
                            <Card.Title>А2</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted"> 420 x 594 мм</Card.Subtitle>
                            <Card.Text>
                            <img src = {A2} width = "370" height = "550"/>
                            </Card.Text>
                            <Card.Link href="#">Card Link</Card.Link>
                            <Card.Link href="#">Another Link</Card.Link>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </CardGroup>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
}
```

[https://imgur.com/a/JlHpUe7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk9w3.png)

In other words, I need clicks on cards to return different values.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the functions immideately. You need to write it like;

`onClick={()=> portretSize(2)}`

So it waits for the click.

Comment: Can you mark the answer as well ? You're welcome